# NullInjectorError: No provider for ShowHideService

Tags: angular

I want to open reset password component on click of a button but unfortunately i am getting
**Error:  [ShowHideStatusDirective -> ShowHideService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ShowHideService!** . I am new to angular can anyone help me out yrr, i have shared error image too. How can i solve it programatically? Thanks in advance.

```
      nb-action style="color:black;" title='Reset Password'   style="color:black;font-size: 1.5rem;"(click)="resetsStudentPassword(row.id,row.email,row.name)">
      <i class="pi pi-key" style="font-size: 1.8em;padding:5%;"></i> </nb-action>
```

```
 resetsStudentPassword(userId,email,fullName){
    this.dialogService.open(ResetPassword, {
      context: {
      userId : userId,
      email:email,
      studentName:fullName,
      admin:this.userStore.getUser()['fullName']
      }
    });
  }
```

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges,} from '@angular/core';
import { NbDialogRef, NbToastrService} from '@nebular/theme';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UsersApi } from '../../../@core/backend/common/api/users.api';
import { preventDefault } from '@fullcalendar/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nb-dialog',
    template: `
    <nb-card [style.height.px]="400" [style.width.px]="350" status="success">
        <nb-card-header>
        <div  (click)="Back()">
        <i title="Back To Course"  class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x fa-pull-right fa-border"></i>
       </div>
        </nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-body>
           <form [formGroup]="resetPasswordForm">
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12">
           <mat-form-field class="form-element">
           <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="passwordCtrl" showHideInput id="passwordOne" [(ngModel)]="numbers">
           <mat-hint>Choose a password of at least six characters</mat-hint>
           <mat-error *ngIf="!resetPasswordForm.controls['passwordCtrl'].valid && resetPasswordForm.controls['passwordCtrl'].touched">
             {{ getErrorPassword() }}
           </mat-error>
           <i class="material-icons" matSuffix showHideTrigger="passwordOne" [showHideStatus]="{ materialIcon: true, id: 'passwordOne' }"></i>
         </mat-form-field>
           </div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
         <mat-form-field class="form-element">
         <input matInput  type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" formControlName="conPasswordCtrl" showHideInput id="passwordTwo" [(ngModel)]="numbers">
         <mat-hint>Choose a password of at least six characters</mat-hint>
         <mat-error *ngIf="!resetPasswordForm.controls['conPasswordCtrl'].valid && resetPasswordForm.controls['conPasswordCtrl'].touched">
           {{ getErrorPassword() }}
         </mat-error>
         <i class="material-icons" matSuffix showHideTrigger="passwordTwo" [showHideStatus]="{ materialIcon: true, id: 'passwordTwo' }"></i>
       </mat-form-field>
         </div>
       </div>
       <br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
       <button nbButton shape="semi-round" hero  size="small" status="primary" (click)="setRandomPassword()">generate Password</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button nbButton shape="semi-round" hero size="small" status="primary" class="mat-button" (click)="passwordValue()">Set Password</button>
      </div> 
<br>
       <div class="row">    
       </div>    
           </form>
        </nb-card-body>
        <nb-card-footer>
        </nb-card-footer>
    </nb-card>
    `,
    styles:[`mat-button:{
        margin-left:10%
    }`]
})

export class ResetPassword {
  @Input() userId: any;
  @Input() email: any;
  @Input() studentName: any;
  @Input() admin: any;
  resetPasswordForm:FormGroup
  password: any;
  conPassword: any;
  numbers:string
  constructor(protected ref: NbDialogRef<ResetPassword>,
              private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
              private userApi: UsersApi,
              private toasterService:NbToastrService,) {
                  this.resetPassword();
  }
   
  ngOnInit(){
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.ref.close();
  }
resetPassword(){
    this.resetPasswordForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    passwordCtrl:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6)]],
    conPasswordCtrl:['',Validators.required,,Validators.minLength(6)]
    })}
  }
```

Comment: Please do NOT use images when the content of the error itself can be pasted into the question. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to properly ask questions.

Comment: is this part of the ShowHideService?
`this.dialogService.open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very self-explanatory - you're missing a provider for the `ShowHideService` which is injected into your `ShowHideStatusDirective`.

Note that `MatDialog` service is, if I remember correctly, injected in the root of the application and uses a scoped factory to create components. This means that if you want your `ResetPassword` component to use the `ShowHideStatusDirective`, the `ShowHideService` needs to be provided either in the root of your application or in your `ResetPassword` component directly.

It's hard to say more based on the code you provided, but the above information should be enough for you to fix the issue.

You can read more on DI in the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).